# How can I get JBoss Developer Studio to auto-indent line comments with command+/?

Tags: java, jboss, comments, jboss-developer-studio

When I comment a line of code in JBoss Developer Studio with `command+/`, it makes the comment left-aligned. Instead, I'd like the comment to follow the indentation size of my code block. How can I accomplish this?

Current

```
private static String transformSymbolicName(String unformatted) {
//  String formatted = unformatted.replace('-', '.').toLowerCase();
    return formatted;
}
```

Desired

```
private static String transformSymbolicName(String unformatted) {
    // String formatted = unformatted.replace('-', '.').toLowerCase();
    return formatted;
}
```

[image: JBoss > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Comments]

Tools: JBoss Developer Studio 8, JDK 1.7.0_80, macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Go to

1. Window -> Preferences
2. on the left unwrap Java -> Code Style, choose
   Formatter
3. Click Edit...
4. Go to Comments tab In General Settings block and remove tick for:

   a. Never indent line comments on first column

   b. Never indent block comments on first column

   You can see how it affects in the Preview window on the right
5. Change profile name on the top and click Apply.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. I want the indentation to apply right when I type `command+/` to insert the comment.

Comment: Andrew, after you make the changes i've described you'll be able to do what you want with `command+/`. You don't need to do all these steps every time. It's done once

Comment: I already had those settings in my Java formatting. `command+/` still doesn't indent comments.

Comment: could you please, provide the screenshot of the Comments tab In General Settings block of the 4th step?